# SmokePreview - A chat addon for the SmokeDetector

Tags: script, chat, greasemonkey

## SmokePreview

A [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) script
to add a preview to chat messages of the [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector).

Messages which are deleted while loading the preview will get a opacity of 50%
to make clear that this is not relevant.

### How can I get it?

1. Install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (for Firefox) or
   [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)
   (for Chrome)
2. Install the user script by clicking [here](https://github.com/rekire/SmokePreview/raw/master/SmokePreview.user.js)
   or install the [development version](https://github.com/rekire/SmokePreview/raw/develop/SmokePreview.user.js)
   which will been updated more often (theoretically).

### Planned features

- Add option to mark a message as spam from the chat.
- Hide preview when a user send a gone message.

### How does it look?

[image: Preview]
[image: A deleted post]

### I like it but...

- There is a bug: Please report it on [GitHub](https://github.com/rekire/SmokePreview/issues)
- How can I contribute a patch or a bugfix? Also on [GitHub](https://github.com/rekire/SmokePreview/pulls)
- Is there no homepage? Well it is work in progress and for now not very helpful, but that could change: http://rekire.github.io/SmokePreview/

Comment: Nice, but is it possible without any monkeys?

Comment: @berserk, looking at the ***current*** code, it should run on almost any browser's userscript engine/extension.

Comment: @brock which browsers and userscript engines did I miss in your opinion?

Comment: You didn't miss any.  You just stated that GM or TM was required -- which is a perfectly valid restriction; those are often the only 2 scenarios I support. ... Berserk objected and looking at the current code, it may also run on Safari, Opera, Violentmonkey, etc..  It's up to Berserk to test those if you (rightly) don't care to explicitly support them.

Comment: Could there be some visual feedback about whether or not I successfully flagged the post as spam?

Comment: There should be a checkmark (✔) at the end of line after a successful report. Maybe there is somewhere still a bug.